# How can I type unicode characters without using the mouse?

Tags: keyboard, unicode

I want to type unicode characters with the keyboard.  I'm looking for a solution with **no mouse usage**.  For example, below I have a line with the unicode "PILE-OF-POO" character:

The codepoint for PILE OF POO is U+1F4A9 and on a linux operating system I can create this character by typing:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>,

<kbd>1</kbd>, 
<kbd>f</kbd>, 
<kbd>4</kbd>, 
<kbd>a</kbd>, 
<kbd>9</kbd>

<kbd>space</kbd>

How can I do something similar on a mac keyboard?  Other answers I've searched involve fiddling with menus and switching input sources.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the characters popover.

[image: Open character popover]

Then type in part of the character's natural-language name (eg "arrow), or the exact Unicode code point (below) and press the down arrow to select the symbol.

[image: Type in code point]

Then simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the character at the location of your previous cursor.

Additional information:

Note the icon in the top right of the character popover.  It changes the popover to the full Character Viewer, which cannot be navigated by the keyboard.  Click the icon in the top right of the Character Viewer to return to the popover.  Many thanks to @Tom Gewecke for this information.

Comment: I don't think this will work if you normally have the expanded version of the Character Viewer active.  You have to use the mouse to get back to the small one you are showing.  Or is there a keyboard shortcut to do that?

Comment: That's right, this only works with the popover variant not the bigger window.

Comment: How do you get the popover variant?  Is there something similar on IOS?  Having frequently used right at the top is great.

Comment: @WGroleau To get the popover, you click on the small icon in the top right corner of the expanded version. For iOS I think you could use an app like Unicode Pad  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unicode-pad/id374098312?mt=8

Comment: Would be nice if it would show the code value, like IPA Palette <https://www.blugs.com/IPA/> does

Comment: I had to use the mouse to get the cursor inside the search box of the popover. Keyboard focus was still in the application and not in the popover. I have a bunch of keyboard mods, like SizeUp and Karabiner, going, so I am not sure about the default behavior.

Comment: Fantastic answer that doesn't require switching input sources!

Comment: Pushing ENTER is not inputting the selected character for me; it just closes the Character Viewer popover. Tried in Notes, Sublime Text 3, and Chrome on High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: Good, but forgets to mention that it doesn't work with non-visible caracter. At least NO-BREAK SPACE Unicode character (u+0160).

Comment: So on my Macbook this works: "Control+Command+Space u+1f4a9 return return" to get 

Comment: Is there any way to trigger the character popover irrespective of the application? For example, on my machine it works in editors like Sublime but not in others (like R Studio), and also not in Firefox, even when the cursor is in a text field.

Answer (score 57):

U+1F4A9 converts to d83d dca9 in unicode hex input, which is what OS X uses as an official input source across the OS.

To use the keyboard directly with their code numbers, first enable Unicode Hex Input in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources. Then, each time you wish to use that input method, switch to the Unicode Hex layout (this can be done via a keyboard shortcut that by default conflicts with spotlight) and then hold the option/alt modifier while you type the the utf-16 hex codes you wish (which is really two hex codes for characters beyond the Unicode BMP, such as 1f4a9, which is represented by d83d dca9).

<kbd>option</kbd> held down then <kbd>d</kbd>,
<kbd>8</kbd>,
<kbd>3</kbd>, 
<kbd>d</kbd>, 
<kbd>d</kbd>, 
<kbd>c</kbd>, 
<kbd>a</kbd>, 
<kbd>9</kbd>

A which point, you will have summoned

Not much fun to type.

If you have a finite number of such characters you want to make, you can set up keyboard shortcuts for them in system prefs/keyboard/text in the substitutions table.

Comment: substitutions could be an acceptable workaround.  I tried setting up a substitution for pileofpoo ->  , but it isn't doing anything.  Could you add more details of how/where this is supposed to work?

Comment: No, trying in text boxes in the browser, in jetbrains IDE , in the built-in terminal app, sublime text ... not working in any of those

Comment: Can you input that character using the Character Viewer in those apps?

Comment: Test of your shortcut using my Safari browser, which has Substitutions in the Edit menu:    Perhaps those apps do not yet support Apple's substitutions system?  Or the color emoji font?

Comment: It works in Safari browser.  When I type `pileofpoo <space>` it was automatically changed to the unicode character.  Unfortunately, **a solution that only works in Apple's applications is not an acceptable solution**.  Ideally it should be system-wide but at the very least, I would like it in the terminal and my browser (Chrome).

Comment: Perhaps a 3rd party text expander like Typeit4me would work with all apps.  But not all apps are guaranteed to support color emoji.

Comment: If you don't enable unicode hex input, you get `∂•£∂∂çåª` output.  @bmike your edits are confusing the post a bit and should be reordered.

Comment: For those not familiar with using the surrogate characters (UTF-16), the conversion is like this:

    1f4a9 -> f4a9 -> 03d,0a9 -> d800+03d,dc00+0a9 -> d83d,dca9
    Subtract 0x10000, High/Low ten bits, Add Hi/Lo surrogate bases

Comment: @dmaestro12 please explain the conversion of f4 to 3d in the first byte of f4a9 -> 03d,0a9. The difference is b7, the bitwise and and ors are also not illuminating for me, so I don't see the connection.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin  The f4 > 3d is the result of applying the 400 in the utf-16 forumula as found e.g. at  http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=iws-appendixa

Comment: @Reb.Cabin It's 0x0f4 >> 2 (shift operation, the most significant 10 bits of 04fa9). Then 0x4a9 & 0x3ff (least significant 10 bits of 04fa9).

Answer (score 20):

In System Preference, select "Keyboard", then select "Input Sources". The left hand pane will show your preferred language keyboard, and possibly alternates. If Unicode Hex Input is not there, click the + button beneath; you will get a long list of languages. Scroll to the very bottom and choose others. Unicode Hex Input will appear in the right pane, then click the Add button, bottom right.

Tab over to Shortcuts and choose the shortcut key. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> may already be taken by Spotlight. Either disable them, or reassign by clicking at the right-hand end of the column and typing your new key. I left them as they were and assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> for Input sources.

If you do that, now when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, you will see the little flag, top right of the menu bar change to a U+. You can then enter your hex codes (which you can find out from the Emoji & Character Viewer) by **holding** <kbd>Alt</kbd> while you type the numbers. E.g. for `U+2282 SUPERSET OF` taken from any lookup source, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2282</kbd> produced the Set member symbol ⊂.

Comment: When adding the input source, after pressing the + at the bottom of the screen instead of scrolling to the bottom you can enter "unicode" in the search field and it should show you the Unicode Hex Input as a result.  Confirmed to work on macOS 10.12

Comment: At least on Mac OS 10.11 there's an option in System Preferences to show input sources in the menubar, so it's easy to switch (of course using your mouse).

Comment: I got this all turned on. Now when I type option d83ddca9 I see nothing until I type one more character, such as 0, 1, ..., e. Option d83ddca90 yields 쪐, option d83ddca91 yields 쪑, ... option d83ddca9e yields 쪞. With all that Hangul, there must be a pile-of-poo somewhere.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin  Do you have that problem here?  I don't   

Comment: @TomGewecke must have been a glitch my side. it's working for me now.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin I know it's related to the question but that's one of the funniest comments I have read in a long, long time and it was very much appreciated. Thanks for that more than two years later!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be creating a custom keyboard layout which will include the characters you want.

Most of the characters mapped to <kbd>Option (⌥)</kbd> + letters (e.g. `Ω≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥˚∆˙ƒ∂ßåœ∑...`) are probably never used by anyone so those can be remapped to output your own symbols/emojis.

A mac keyboard layout can be an XML or a .bundle file and you can use the free app [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) to clone an existing layout, modify the mappings as you need, and then export and install the new layout. The app is only used the create the layout so it does not need to be loaded in the system memory like some shortcut mapping apps do.

Also see https://superuser.com/questions/665494/how-to-make-a-custom-keyboard-layout-in-os-x