# Entering emoji on Mac with keyboard only

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, emoji

I know that there is a keyboard shortcut to bring up the special characters and emoji dialog. (On my Mac you just press the function key once, but I think by default it's ctrl-cmd-space.)

However, you still have to select the emoji from an on-screen menu. I am wondering if there is a way to do it using the keyboard alone. If I want to type, say,  or , is there any way to do it without using the trackpad or touch bar at all, only the keyboard?

Comment: There is a similar question at  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332746/how-to-use-character-viewer-with-only-keyboard-and-no-mouse   and at  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183045/how-can-i-type-unicode-characters-without-using-the-mouse

Comment: Oh gosh, I feel silly now. The character viewer *can* be used with only the keyboard. It does have focus when you trigger it - but only if you're actually typing in a text box at the time. So then the first answer suggested by @TomGewecke answers my question

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so - as a window it doesn't present itself as 'frontmost'. You can't switch to it with either  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>  or even the wildly random  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>F4</kbd> .

If there are some you use a lot, you could set them to text replacements, with short, easy to remember triggers…

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea - for some reason I hadn't thought of using that feature for this.