# One key is not working anymore

Tags: macos, keyboard

The 0 (zero) key on my Mac keyboard does not work anymore. Is there some kind of ascii code to type this character?

Comment: With tast I mean key.

Comment: Mac's can't use ascii codes like Windows.  If you switch to the Unicode Hex keyboard as bmike suggests, you can get it by holding option and typing the hex code, 0030.  Much better to set up a replace - with shortcut in system preferences/keyboard/text.

Comment: @TomGewecke You always have the perfect answers for internationalization and key layouts. Please feel free to edit my posts or @ me whenever you have a better answer to make than mine.

Comment: @bmike Good idea, a couple edits is better than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to connect a USB keyboard if you need to make a change or enter 0 as part of a password, but once you're logged in you can copy / paste the 0 and also enable the keyboard viewer in system preferences.

That lets you get a 0 from the pointer / mouse / trackpad

Additionally, you could shift your keyboard mapping to Dvorak (left or right) and use a different physical key until you decide to get it repaired or see if you're ok using unicode hex input method.

With the unicode hex keyboard, you hold down option and type hex (0030 for zero) instead of ascii code.

- [How can I type unicode characters without using the mouse?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183045/how-can-i-type-unicode-characters-without-using-the-mouse)

The main problem with unicode entry is the 0 is used quite a lot, so you'll probably want to set up a shortcut to convert another character to 0 or get a bluetooth keyboard.

To make a shortcut, go to system preferences/keyboard/text/replace with.  To create a custom layout where 0 is on a working key, try [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).